# RACKET How do I create a score counter?

Tags: user-interface, racket, counter

I need to create a score counter for my tetris game project in Racket and I'm stuck... It's ment to count +100, +250, +400 or +600 depending if one, two, three or four rows get deleted. The main problem for me is that I dont know in what class% I'm supposed to do it in.. The result should look something like this:

[image]

I have the the other parts done, only the score window is missing. The only idea I have on how to create it is with a button that you can click and the score gets updated. The callback procedure for that button would look something like this:

```
[callback (lambda (button event)
               (cond
                 ((eq? delete-row 1) (send *score-button* set-label (+ (send *score-button* get-label) 100)))
                 ((eq? delete-row 2) (send *score-button* set-label (+ (send *score-button* get-label) 250)))
                 ((eq? delete-row 3) (send *score-button* set-label (+ (send *score-button* get-label) 400)))
                 ((eq? delete-row 4) (send *score-button* set-label (+ (send *score-button* get-label) 600)))
                 ))]
```

delete-row is the procedure that takes care of the rows if they get filled (not mentioned in the code). However, I'm not sure if it even works and it feels very unprofessional, rather doing it some other way...

Anyone with an idea on how I can create this score counter? I appreciate all answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page show the various types of GUI elements:

http://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/Widget_Gallery.html?q=text%25

Is it a `message%` you want?

Comment: Didn't know about that gallery, thanks! message% looks good, the important thing is that I can update it everytime my delete-row procedure runs.